# differences between log and logger

Tags: java, logging

I have seen `log` and `logger` as follows,

```
public static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.class)
logger.debug something

private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.class)
log.debug(something)
```

Are there any difference between `log` and `logger`?

Note: They are both from *apache.commons*.

Comment: The name of the variable makes no difference: you might as well call it `xyz12309218349087` - the effect is going to be the same (the readability is going to suffer, though).

Comment: Apart from the fact that one is declared "public static" and the other "private", and that they have different names, no... (please confirm something: the code does not actually read `this.class`, does it? That would not compile)

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference is not in the names `log` and `logger` (they are different names for a variable of the same type and initialized in the same way, but in this:

```
public static final Log logger;
private final Log log;
```

Being `final`, which both are, they cannot be modified once initialized.

However, `private` means that the variable is only accessible within the class. The `public` modifier means that the variable is accessible to all classes that imported or are within the package.

When an object is `static`, like `logger`, there is one value for the entire program; when it is not, like `log`, it is instantiated with each instance of the object.

Answer (score 0):

As [La-comadreja stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22333955/1762224), you defined two variables with completely different modifiers.

- Binding

  - Static (`static`) – compile-time
  - Instance – dynamic
- Access

  - Public (`public`) – global-scope
  - Protected (`protected`) – package-scope or subclass-scope
  - Private (`private`) – class-scope
  - Default – Same as protected (except the subclass needs to also be in the same package)
- Assignment

  - Final (`final`) – cannot be reassigned (except within the constructor)
  - Default – Can be reassigned

---

Now I am thinking that you really meant, "what is the difference between the following?":

```java
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

```java
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

Where the only distinction is the name of the variable that is being assigned. It just comes to down convention. Both `log` and `logger` are used across the board. The only difference is how many characters you want to type.

- [SLF4J docs](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) uses `logger`
- [Log4j docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/usage.html) uses `logger`
- [Logback docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html) uses `logger`
- [Apache Commons Logging docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html) uses `log`
- [Lombok convention](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j) i.e. `@SLF4J` uses `log`